C# WPF AutoCompleteBox select first element when pressing Tab button
I use an AutoCompleteBox to filter a large list.
Currently when not pressing KeyDown or clicking an element of the list by mouse, nothing is selected when I press Tab button.
How to select the first entry of the currently filtered list, when pressing the tab button?
Here is the current code of the autocompletebox:
           <controls:AutoCompleteBox x:Name="KundennummerTextBox" Margin="0,5,0,0"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Adressen}" 
                                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAdresse, Mode=TwoWay}" MinimumPrefixLength="2" MinimumPopulateDelay="300" TabIndex="0"
                                      FilterMode="Contains" IsTextCompletionEnabled="True" Style="{StaticResource DefaultAutoCompleteBoxStyle}" >
                <controls:AutoCompleteBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Style.Resources>
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Gray"/>
                        </Style.Resources>
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                    <Grid x:Name="KundennummerTextBoxDetails" Width="395" Margin="3,3,3,3">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <TextBlock Margin="0,5,0,5" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Adresse}"/>
                                        <TextBlock Margin="0,5,0,5" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Matchcode}"/>
                                        <TextBlock Margin="0,5,0,5" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Kundennummer}"/>
                                        <TextBlock Margin="0,5,0,5" Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding Mandant}"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="controls:AutoCompleteBox.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                            <Setter TargetName="KundennummerTextBoxDetails" Property="Background" Value="Gray"></Setter>
                                            <!--<Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />-->
                                            <Setter TargetName="KundennummerTextBoxDetails" Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="TextElement.Background" Value="Gray" />
                                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="Gray" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </controls:AutoCompleteBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            </controls:AutoCompleteBox>

